# Two Objects Sharing the same list

Tags: python, python-2.7

**CODE:**

```
    class matrix():

    row=0
    colum=0
    def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.m=[]
        self.row=x
        self.colum=y
        #Makes a empty matrix of size x*y
        for i in range(self.row):
            self.m.append([])
            for j in range(self.colum):
                self.m[i].append(int(raw_input("Enter element")))
#To diplay the matrix
def display(x):
    k=x.m
    for i in range(0,x.row):
            for j in range(0,x.colum):
                k[i][j]=x.m[i][j]
    return k
row1=int(raw_input("Enter Number of rows of 1st Matrix"))
colum1=int(raw_input("Enter Number of colume of 1st Martrix"))
matrix1=matrix(row1,colum1)
print "1st Matrix:",display(matrix1) # displaying the first matix before adding elements
row2=int(raw_input("Enter Number of rows of 2nd Matrix"))
colum2=int(raw_input("Enter Number of colume of 2nd Martrix"))
matrix2=matrix(row2,colum2)
print "Matrix 2:",display(matrix2) #displaying the second matrix before adding elements
```

**Output:**

```
Enter Number of rows of 1st Matrix2
Enter Number of colume of 1st Martrix2
Enter element11
Enter element22
Enter element33
Enter element44
1st Matrix: [[11, 22], [33, 44]]
Enter Number of rows of 2nd Matrix2
Enter Number of colume of 2nd Martrix3
Enter element1
Enter element2
Enter element3
Enter element4
Enter element5
Enter element6
Matrix 2: [[11, 22, 1, 2, 3], [33, 44, 4, 5, 6], [], []]
```

I Have written the following code in python 2.7 and what I expect to happen, is to create two matix of given size using the constructor of class matrix.
As Shown in the output both the object i.e matrix1 and matrix2 share the same list m. Shouldn't two seprate list we used to store this by default.
The Expected Matrix 2 is

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Comment: Because you initialize your 'm' list when class is created. Move it to __init__

Comment: @Alex Thanks That solved it. But why didnt what i did work?. Isnt it the same thing

Comment: m list is linked to a class but not to it's instance. So all instance of a class matrix will share it. if you put it to __init__ it will create a new list each time an instance is created. That is the difference.

Comment: @Alex Oh is there a way to link the list m to each instance and is this only for list or other data types as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `def display` function into the class itself.  This becomes a method you call from the `matrix` object, i.e. `matrix1.display()`.   The variables `m`, `row`, and `column` are currently not getting saved within the `matrix` object.  Try the code below.

```
class matrix(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.m = []
        self.row = x
        self.colum = y
        #Makes a empty matrix of size x*y
        for i in range(self.row):
            self.m.append([])
            for j in range(self.colum):
                self.m[i].append(int(raw_input("Enter element ({},{}): ".format(i,j))))

    #To diplay the matrix
    def display(self):
        for r in self.m:
            print(r)


>>> matrix1 = matrix(2,2)
Enter element (0, 0): 11
Enter element (0, 1): 22
Enter element (1, 0): 33
Enter element (1, 1): 44

>>> matrix1.display()
[11, 22]
[33, 44]
```